# mySQL - how can I log who is writing records to my database table

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL database hosted on a remote server.
It is version 5.0.96.
Someone is writing records to my table 'orders' and I would like to log who is doing this and from where.
I have read many posts about log(s) and most of what I have found so far are ways to modify my .ini file on my system, etc.
But, since this is not on any machines that I can access, I am looking for a way to track these record ads so I can see where they are coming from.
Any assistance on how to do this would be very helpful.
Rich

Answer (score 0):

you could add a new table called log , and write a trigger to insert:

CONNECTION_ID(), SYSTEM_USER()

on to the log table when an update/insert or delete happens on other tables.

at least this is how i would fix this problem .

there is a nice code you could use as your reference on git-hub which i will link (it is not mine)

[Link to Github page](https://gist.github.com/bimalpoudel/9087671)

Comment: Thanks, Sina.
I followed that link, and was able to create a log table.
However, I am having trouble creating a trigger on the 'orders' table.
I am getting some errors, including one error saying that the 'orders' table already exists. Why is it trying to create the table?
Thanks, for any further insight.

Comment: All i can guess from the error given , is that you are trying to build a new table which has the name "orders"

Comment: check the top of the code if it is creating something new or updating it

Comment: Here is what I am running.
USE `homespecv3`;

DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS homespecv3.orders_AINS$$
USE `homespecv3`$$
CREATE TRIGGER `orders_AINS` AFTER INSERT ON orders FOR EACH ROW
-- Edit trigger body code below this line. Do not edit lines above this one
INSERT INTO audit_connections (
 `connection_id`, user_host, connected_on
) VALUES (
 CONNECTION_ID(), CURRENT_USER(), NOW()
) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
 connections_counter = connections_counter+1,
 connected_on = NOW()
;

$$
DELIMITER ;

Comment: How do you format this text properly to show the code lines?

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER orders_AINS , I think this the problem each time you are running this I think it tries to "CREATE" a new Trigger called "orders_AINS" while it is already there !

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this implementation of the mySQL database does not grant the necessary privileges to allow the creation of any triggers.
Also, they do not have any tools to monitor or trap writes to determine from where they are originating.